# CWiFiDisplayException on Windows 10 due to Miracast

Tags: c++, directx-9

We are getting a rare crash for some Windows 10 users and it is somehow related to Miracast. It is the same issue reported [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cwifidisplayexception-on-windows-10-due-to-miracas/1149640) with code to reproduce, but sadly there was no solution. I copied the code and stacktrace from the ticket.

Code from link above

```
#pragma comment(lib, "dxguid.lib")
#include <dxdiag.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
  CoInitialize(NULL);

  IDxDiagProvider* dxDiagProvider;
  IDxDiagContainer* rootContainer;
  if (SUCCEEDED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DxDiagProvider, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IDxDiagProvider, (LPVOID*)&dxDiagProvider)))
  {
    DXDIAG_INIT_PARAMS initParams;
    initParams.dwSize = sizeof(DXDIAG_INIT_PARAMS);
    initParams.dwDxDiagHeaderVersion = 111;
    initParams.bAllowWHQLChecks = false;
    initParams.pReserved = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(dxDiagProvider->Initialize(&initParams)) && SUCCEEDED(dxDiagProvider->GetRootContainer(&rootContainer)))
    {
      IDxDiagContainer* childContainer;
      // ---- Following line throws exception ----
      if (SUCCEEDED(rootContainer->GetChildContainer(L"DxDiag_DisplayDevices", &childContainer)))
        childContainer->Release();
      rootContainer->Release();
    }
    dxDiagProvider->Release();
  }

  CoUninitialize();
}
```

Stacktrace from link above

```
00 006befa4 767f336e     KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x62
01 006befbc 767f3346     RPCRT4!RpcpRaiseException+0x27
02 006befc8 7683cc3c     RPCRT4!RpcRaiseException+0x16
03 006beff4 767e6902     RPCRT4!GenericHandleMgr+0x202d7
04 006bf474 767e49a4     RPCRT4!NdrClientCall2+0xe62
05 006bf488 7bdc415e     RPCRT4!NdrClientCall4+0x14
06 006bf4ec 7bdbb2d3     wlanapi!WFDOpenHandleLib+0x8e7e
07 006bf4f8 79cc9e6e     wlanapi!WFDOpenHandle+0x13
08 006bf51c 79cc95f0     WiFiDisplay!WiFiDisplayUtil::WfdHandle::Open+0x2c
09 006bf548 79b73c14     WiFiDisplay!IsMiracastSupportedByWlan+0x20
0a 006bf570 79b6fc3b     dxdiagn!GetDisplayWDDM1_3FeatureSupport+0x4f
0b 006bf704 79b6fe2c     dxdiagn!GetPropertiesForInterfaces+0x5c6
0c 006bf848 79b5fedc     dxdiagn!EnumDisplayInterfaces_SetupDi+0x1db
0d 006bf964 79b5e029     dxdiagn!CDxDiagProvider::ExecMethod+0x3ac
0e 006bfa50 79b5dccd     dxdiagn!CDxDiagProvider::GetChildContainerHelper+0x25d
0f 006bfd30 79b6a449     dxdiagn!GetChildContainer+0x291
10 006bfd40 007317ff     dxdiagn!CDxDiagClassObject::GetChildContainer+0x19
11 006bfe60 007320b3     CppScratchpad!main+0xdf [C:\Projects\CppScratchpad\CppScratchpad\main.cpp @ 23]
```

Our stacktrace

```
KERNELBASE.dll!_RaiseException@16()    Unknown
     rpcrt4.dll!RpcpRaiseException()    Unknown
     rpcrt4.dll!_RpcRaiseException@4()    Unknown
     rpcrt4.dll!GenericHandleMgr()    Unknown
     rpcrt4.dll!_NdrClientCall2()    Unknown
     rpcrt4.dll!_NdrClientCall4()    Unknown
     wlanapi.dll!WFDOpenHandleLib()    Unknown
     wlanapi.dll!_WFDOpenHandle@12()    Unknown
     WiFiDisplay.dll!WiFiDisplayUtil::WfdHandle::Open(void)    Unknown
     WiFiDisplay.dll!_IsMiracastSupportedByWlan@0()    Unknown
     dxdiagn.dll!GetDisplayWDDM1_3FeatureSupport(class DisplayInfo *)    Unknown
     dxdiagn.dll!GetPropertiesForInterfaces(class DisplayInfo * *,void *,struct _DO_DEVINFO_DATA *,class CSmartStrTemplate<unsigned short,64> &,int,void *,struct _SP_DEVINFO_DATA *)    Unknown
     dxdiagn.dll!EnumDisplayInterfaces_SetupDi(class DisplayInfo * *)    Unknown
     dxdiagn.dll!CDxDiagProvider::ExecMethod(unsigned short const *,struct tagVARIANT *)    Unknown
     dxdiagn.dll!CDxDiagProvider::GetChildContainerHelper(class CDxDiagClassObject *,class std::vector<class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > > > &,class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)    Unknown
     dxdiagn.dll!GetChildContainer(class CDxDiagProvider &,class CSmartStrTemplate<unsigned short,64> &,unsigned short const *,struct IDxDiagContainer * *)    Unknown
     dxdiagn.dll!CDxDiagClassObject::GetChildContainer(unsigned short const *,struct IDxDiagContainer * *)    Unknown
     RendDX9.dll!07ad5ed9()    Unknown
```

Comment: This depends heavily on hardware. WiFiDisplayUtil probably throws because there was an error with WFDOpenHandle. What you can do is try to simply call WFDOpenHandle which is documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wfdopenhandle by yourself (pass WFD_API_VERSION = 1 as 1st argument). The error number may give you more information

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I created a test program like that and send it to the client. Now have to wait for him to test it out.